# Looping Smoke Animation

Tags: animation

I'm working on a game right now and I'm using Blender to create animations, which I render to 2D and implement into my game. I'm trying to use a smoke animation for a power plant in the game and use like a 2 second clip that is seamless and loops perfectly to make the smoke appear to be continuously coming out of the power plant. Is this possible using quick smoke? The solution does not necessarily have to involve Blender, I render to a collection of animation frames which can be played or manipulated however within the game engine.

Thanks in advance!